# Rpy2 error: "No module named _rinterface"?

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I am getting the following error when trying to load [rpy2](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2.html):

```
>>> from rpy2 import robjects
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy2\robjects\__init__.py", line 14, in <m
odule>
    import rpy2.rinterface as rinterface
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\rpy2\rinterface\__init__.py", line 78, in
<module>
    from rpy2.rinterface._rinterface import *
ImportError: No module named _rinterface
```

I'm using R 2.11.1, Python 2.6.5, and rpy2 2.2.2.0.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am unsure that there is currently MSWindows support for rpy2 (and this since version 2.0.8). Should there be a build somewhere, I am sure that there would be interest in seeing it contributed.

Comment: Really?  That sucks.  Thanks @lgautier!

Comment: Have you considered PypeR?  I haven't tried it yet.  I believe [this is its homepage](http://www.webarray.org/softwares/PypeR/), and [this is an article about it](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v35/c02/paper), comparing it to Rpy and Rpy2.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is that rinterface is having trouble locating R on your box. In unix, you can solve this by updating the bashrc profile (typically located at /etc/bashrc). There, you'd add a line like this: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/R

There must be something similar in windows...